# Only whitespaces in string find_first_not_of() vs find_last_not_of()

Tags: c++, whitespace

I want to check if a wstring only contains whitespaces (to be precise: " \t\r\n"). I've found several solutions using the method `find_last_not_of()`.

I've got 2 questions regarding this method:

1. when i know that in the cases where the wstring will contain non-whitespace-characters, those characters will be at the beginning of the string, wouldn't it be better if I'd use `find_first_not_of()` since it returns as soon as it found something?
2. do both methods have a complexity of O(n) or am i wrong here?

I know there's a lot of information about these methods in the web, but i've found some contradictory statements on this topic.

Comment: BTW, the only difference between `find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of` should be the direction of iteration.`find_last_not_of` shouldn't iterate from the beginning, as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `std::basic_string::find_last_not_of` is implemented is not part of the specification; thus we can't say if the characters are looked up in natural or reversed order.

Hence,

1. Implementation-dependent
2. Implementation-dependent

Let's have a look of the [libstdc++'s implementation of `std::basic_string::find_last_not_of`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00754_source.html) (basic_string.tcc):

```
1317   template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
1318     typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
1319     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
1320     find_last_not_of(const _CharT* __s, size_type __pos, size_type __n) const
1321     {
1322       __glibcxx_requires_string_len(__s, __n);
1323       size_type __size = this->size();
1324       if (__size)
1325    {
1326      if (--__size > __pos)
1327        __size = __pos;
1328      do
1329        {
1330          if (!traits_type::find(__s, __n, _M_data()[__size]))
1331            return __size;
1332        }
1333      while (__size--);
1334    }
1335       return npos;
1336     }
```

As one could have guessed, the string is looked up backward. In your specific case, `std::basic_string::find_first_not_of` should be the way to go.

Comment: thanks a lot! this implementation answers both of my questions! its complexity is O(n) and i know which one to use!

Comment: The term "implementation-defined" in the standard means that an implementation can do what it wants, but has to document it. This is not the case here, so it's "unspecified".

Comment: The character look up order is unspecified, but the answer the OP's questions are implementation-dependent, aren't them?